# R Cycling through all webpages on a website

Tags: html, r, loops

I'm struggling with a piece of web scraping. I'm attempting to cycle through all the web pages on a retailers site in an attempt to pull back item codes, product descriptions and pricings. So far I have this code

```
> fileUrl <- "http://www.boots.com/en/LOreal-Paris-Revitalift-Laser-Renew-Peeling-Lotion-Night_1493102/"
> doc <- htmlTreeParse(fileUrl,useInternal=TRUE)
> codes <- xpathSApply(doc,"//p[@class='itemNumber']",xmlValue)
> desc <- xpathSApply(doc,"//span[@itemprop='name']",xmlValue)
> price <- xpathSApply(doc,"//span[@itemprop='price']",xmlValue)
```

I'm fairly inexperienced with R and these five lines show the size of my empire currently.

This code does indeed pull back the required information but each product has it's own page and there are thousands of products.

What I need is a way to cycle through every webpage on the site and pool this information into one place.

Comment: As currently stated this question is way too broad and may vary greatly depending on the website. Websites are not necessarily designed to be easily scraped. You simply have to spend a lot of time learning how the site is set up and learning how to discover this links of interest to you.

Comment: Really going to have to share the website, or the data with us to be able to answer.

Comment: Have you looked at nutch, an open source suite of tools from Apache for searching URLs on a website?  There is also solr to index the content nutch brings back.

Comment: I've added the url I'm looking at. Thanks for the feedback

lawyeR I didn't even know that existed, I've been having a look at some tutorials and it looks like that's what I might need, unfortunately at work I'm behind a heavy proxy server and so I need to wait until I can trial it.